# RxJS (in Angular): repeat action on partially successful http request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Send a stop request with a saved ID in the URL.
2. Send a request with a new ID in the URL, save the ID.
3. If the response is 200, that's okay. If it's 204, retry from 1 (meaning w/ a new ID).

Best case: without a scaffolding of subscribes(), i.e. only one subscribe at the end, the rest via RxJS's pipe.
The current code looks a lot like this:

```
public doStuff(): Observable<string> {
  if (this.id) {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${STOP_URL}/${this.id}`).pipe(
      tap(() => {
        this.id = Date.now();
      }),
      mergeMap(() => this.httpClient.get(`${START_URL}/${this.id}`))
    );
  } else {/* basically the same but without the stop */}
}
```

And in the component where I'm using it:

```
this.service
  .doStuff()
  .pipe(
    // TODO here comes the repetition with a new ID if response is 204
    mergeMap(result => this.httpClient.get(/* stuff with part of the response */))
).subscribe(foo => bar())
```

Is it possible to add something in that "TODO" line that would (a) actually take into account the response code (which I haven't figured out for now) and (b) repeat the ID generation, too, not only the request with the first generated ID? I'd settle for an answer without (b), too, it just wouldn't be very clean. But I can't figure out how to repeat the request on a 204 response because stuff like retryWhen() only works if it's a !== 2XX code. repeat() doesn't work because you can't include logic and repeatWhen() has basically no documentation and (afaik) does not have any info about the response in its parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The recursive rxjs operator is expand. Create an object with the parameters you want to use and each time the http client gives an emission map to the same parameters object for the next iteration.

```
of({
  continue: true,
  url: 'url to use'
}).pipe(
  expand(params => http.get(params.url, {observe: 'response'}).pipe(
    map(response => {
      // response.status will give you if it is 200 or not
      const url = logicToCreateNextUrl;
      const continue = logicToDecideToStop;
      return { continue, url };
    })
  )),
  takeWhile(params => params.continue)
).subscribe();
```

You can add anything you want to the parameters object such as a result, it is up to you what you want to go through each time, just map the http response to the next call.

```
of({
  result: undefined,
  url: 'url to use'
}).pipe(
  expand(params => http.get(params.url, {observe: 'response'}).pipe(
    map(response => {
      // response.status will give you if it is 200 or not
      const url = logicToCreateNextUrl;
      const result = logicToDecideIfYouHaveAResultYet;
      return { result, url };
    })
  )),
  filter(params => params.result),
  takeWhile(params => !params.result, true),
  map(params => params.result),
).subscribe(result => {
  // Will only emit once when you put a result on the params object
});
```

Comment: This looks incredibly handy and I have to try it tomorrow. One question though: with how much is going on there, what's the benefit of doing this vs. a classic loop with async-await and a try-catch inside?

Comment: Because we are coding reactively, not using promises.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the effects? I think that this would be the cleanest solution in that case

Just create xxxx

1. In your service just dispatch action `doStuf(id)`
2. Create an effect that will be listening on `doStuf(id)` action and then => send a stop request with a saved ID in the URL within it => dispatch action that `stopSucceded`
3. Create an effect that will be listening on `stopSucceded` => Send a request with a new ID in the URL if the response is 200 => dispatch action `allGoodFinish` if not dispatch action `doStuf(newId)`

Comment: There is no mention of that store pattern cancer in this question

Answer (score 0):

You could do a recursive call using a `BehaviorSubject`. Then use `filter` to test the status code. If the status code is not `200`, then call `next` on the subject and return false to stop the pipe which will repeat the process. Once status is `200` return `true` and complete the pipe to continue on with the flow.

```
doStuff() {
  if (!this.id) return EMPTY; // import {EMPTY} from 'rxjs';
  // Start with the initial url
  const sub = new BehaviorSubject<string>(`${STOP_URL}/${this.id}`);
  return sub.pipe(
    // take(5), // Set a max number of tries if needed.
    // timeout(5000), // End the process if nothing is emitted after x seconds.
    // delay(1000), // Limit how fast requests can go through.
    // Make the request of whatever is in the BehaviorSubject.
    exhaustMap(url => this.httpClient.get(url, {observe: 'response'}))
    // Keep trying until a 200 is returned
    filter(resp => {
      if(resp.status === 200) {
        sub.complete();
        return true;
      }
      this.id = Date.now();
      // Send a new url to the BehaviorSubject. 
      // This will trigger a new request with a new URL.
      sub.next(`${START_URL}/${this.id}`);
      return false;
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: And this does not fill the RAM indefinitely? Looks too good to be true. :D

Comment: It will clean itself up once it gets to the 200 when we call complete. Or you can uncomment the `take()` line and set a limit of tries. You can also add a `delay()` to delay the request limit (aka 1 per second).

Comment: I meant if the response is 204 for a long time. Like, imagine you're waiting for a car to drive into a specific parking slot or you're waiting for a person to open a specific door. And you're doing that on next to no RAM. :'D

Comment: Use the `take()` to only try the request `x` number of times. Its the very first item in the pipe (commented out).

Comment: I used to use subjects that call their own next function like this until I discovered the expand operator, check it out. It is the way I do any recursive stuff now.